# JSON Parser Golang with escape character

Tags: json, go, escaping, unmarshalling

I'm beginner in Golang, and I have a JSON like this :

```
{
   "test": [
      {
         "test": "test",
         "source": "test",
         "description": [
            "test"
         ],
         "getField": "{\"Key\":\"Value\",\"Key\":\"Value\",\"**ThisIsWhatIwant**\":\"test\",\"Key\":Value,\"Key\":0,\"Key\":\"value\",\"Key\":value}"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I do for retrieve the field "**ThisIsWhatIwant**" inside getField JSON ? How Can I use Umarchalled ?

Because In Java I used JsonParser easily but here its more complicated,

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You'll need to unmarshal twice, because the contents of `getField` is just a string as far as JSON is concerned. You'll have to unmarshal the outer document, get the value of `getField`, then unmarshal that into a new value to extract data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Unmarshal the json data twice and note that json data can not have duplicate keys.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type foo struct {
    Test []*bar `json:"test"`
}

type bar struct {
    Test        string   `json:"test"`
    Source      string   `json:"source"`
    Description []string `json:"description"`
    GetField    string   `json:"getField"`
}

type want struct {
    ThisIsWhatIwant string `json:"**ThisIsWhatIwant**"`
}

func main() {
    raw := `
    {
        "test": [
           {
              "test": "test",
              "source": "test",
              "description": [
                 "test"
              ],
              "getField": "{\"**ThisIsWhatIwant**\":\"test\"}"
           }
        ]
     }`

    foo := &foo{}
    // first unmarshal
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), foo)

    want := &want{}
    // second unmarshal
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(foo.Test[0].GetField), want)
    log.Println(want.ThisIsWhatIwant)
}
```